# Writing a nasm loop over tokens

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I would like to write a nasm loop based on a list of N tokens, where some variable takes the value of each token in turn.

Something like:

```
%for reg in {rax, rbx, rcx, rdx, rsi, rdi}
push reg
%endfor
```

To generate:

```
push rax
push rbx
...
push rdi
```

Of course, `%for` doesn't actually exist: it's just a made-up pseudo-directive showing what I want. Is there some way to do this relatively elegantly?

Comment: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html 4.3.8

Comment: @tkausl - right, thanks. This doesn't let me write such a loop "in place" I think: I would extract the specific code for each loop into a macro (e.g., one specific to `push`) and then call it with whatever list of arguments I want, right?

Comment: Correct. You could even write another, second macro, `%pusha` for example, to call `%push` with all the registers so you don't need to list them manually each time, essentially mimicing the `pushad` instruction for x64.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar task in NASM and now I have found it in my 19 years old macrolibrary:

```
;   PUSH   multiple operands
%MACRO PUSH 1-*
    %REP %0
      PUSH %1
      %ROTATE 1
    %ENDREP
%ENDMACRO
```

Almost identical syntax that you quoted above is possible with €ASM:

```
reg %for rax, rbx, rcx, rdx, rsi, rdi
      push %reg
    %endfor
```

But in case of PUSH/POP it is not essential to implement multiple operands with a macro
because it is built-in in the language: https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#InsEnhMultipleOperands

Comment: Right, but the problem is that the macro hardcores the `push` instruction. My question wasn't how to specifically write this `push` loop, but how to write the loop for an arbitrary "body" (which just happens to be `push` in this case). Maybe there is a way to pass the body to the macro?

Comment: Create a macro *Body* beforehand, and replace the  hardwired *PUSH %1* with *Body %1*

Comment: Thanks! This can be repeated by redefining the Body macro repeatedly, right? That is, if I want to use the same loop with different bodies, it's a matter of defining the Body macro each time?